# how to remove first characters of an item within array in python scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to remove the first 7 characters of an item within an array, more specifically im trying to remove "mailto" so it will just render out the email

I thought using [:7] would do the trick however python ignores the request.

any suggestions ?

```
def businessprofile(self, response):
    for business in response.css('header#main-header'):
        item = Item()
        item['business_name'] = business.css('div.sales-info h1::text').extract()
        item['website'] = business.css('a.secondary-btn.website-link::attr(href)').extract()
        # i want to remove the first 7 characters "mailto:", but not sure how ? i made an attempt
        item['email'] = business.css('a.email-business::attr(href)').extract()[7:]
        item['phonenumber'] = business.css('p.phone::text').extract_first()
        for x in item['business_name']:
            #new code here, call to self.seen_business_names
            if x not in self.seen_business_names:
                if item['business_name']:
                    if item['phonenumber']:
                        if item['email']:                               
                            yield item
                            self.seen_business_names.append(x)
```

this is where i need to remove the characters

```
   item['email'] = business.css('a.email-business::attr(href)').extract()[7:]
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input? I think you can solve this using `re`. Pattern matching may not even be necessary, I notice, now that I reread the question.

Comment: can you elaborate more let me update the post and point exactly where i need the fix at.

Comment: What kind of structure does `business.css('a.email-business::attr(href)').extract()` have?

Comment: it extracts emails and outputs the `mailto:myemail@barnowlrocks.com`

Comment: Your code seems to be valid. Where did you test in your code that you didn't received the right string. Why don't you add a print statement `print(business.css('a.email-business::attr(href)').extract()[7:])` and see if that prints the right result. If this is the case: what does the Item class do. Please provide with more information and details (in your original question and not as a comment). Otherwise it is really hard to help you.

Comment: it prints this `[]`

Comment: i even tried this but no luck `item['email'][7:]`

Comment: So `print(business.css('a.email-business::attr(href)').extract()[7:])` prints`[]`. What about `print(business.css('a.email-business::attr(href)').extract())`?

Comment: it prints the email address

Comment: Exactly how does it print? Can we have that output as it is?

Comment: `'business_name': ['The Tenth Street *******'],
 'email': ['mailto:businessname@gmail.com'],
 'phonenumber': '(123) 456-9999',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly `business.css('a.email-business::attr(href)').extract()` returns a list. You need to remove `mailto:` from an item in list.

```
s = business.css('a.email-business::attr(href)').extract()
item['email'] = [item[7:] for item in s]
# ['businessname@gmail.com']
```

Or

```
s = business.css('a.email-business::attr(href)').extract()
item['email'] = [item.replace('mailto:', '') for item in s]
# ['businessname@gmail.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `[7:]` and not `[:7]`

the syntax is `[<start>:<end>]` and when omitted it will be automatically from start or end of the string.

For example:

```
val = "mailto:abc@abc.de"
mailto = val[:7] # from first charater to 7th = 'mailto:'
email = val[7:] # 8th character to the end.
```

Comment: I believe that is actually a typo in the description.

Comment: this code does not correlate to what im trying to achieve ? i do not want to store the array item within a variable, do you have a another way to go about doing this ?

Comment: Can you please provide us with good input data. for example what does `business.css('a.email-business::attr(href)').extract()` return exactly? Is it a string? Without it we cannot answer the question to any more extend. Please put the information in you original question

Comment: it extracts the email like this for ex `mailto:myemail@barnowlrocks.com`

Comment: i want to keep it in this format `item['email'] = business.css('a.email-business::attr(href)').extract()[7:]`

Comment: i think its `email = scrapy.Field()[7:]` however im getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`

Answer (score 0):

The count starts at 0:

```
a = "0123456789"
a[7:]
# '789'
```

So you probably need

```
a[8:]
# '89'
```